# Laravel API testing unit vs feature

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing

I am using Laravel 5.6 to write a API with no views, just endpoints.

I am very new to testing and my understanding is that Unit tests are from a programmers perspective and Feature tests are from a users perspective.

As i am only creating an API, would I be right to assume that i will only be writing Unit tests? and i am safe to remove the tests/Feature directory all together?

My tests will consist of things like

```
public function it_authenticate_a_user()
```

Sorry if its a dull question, i am only trying to learn.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, it's not a good idea to write only unit tests.

A true unit test verifies that a single class or function works as expected. However, it does NOT verify that the whole application works as expected - it's perfectly possible for the application to have 100% coverage from unit tests, but not actually work because the components don't quite fit together as expected. You should also write functional tests for your endpoints. The majority of your tests should be unit tests, but it's a good idea to make sure every API method is covered by functional tests too, just to make sure the pieces fit together.

Put it this way, at Google they advocate a model called the testing pyramid, which gives a typical ratio of 70% unit tests, 20% functional tests, and 10% high level acceptance tests. It should not be seen as rigid, and for an API I see little need for acceptance tests, but it gives some idea as to a healthy mix of tests.

An API is in some ways easier to test than a conventional web app since it's stateless and each method is relatively simple, but it's just as important it has functional test coverage. It's straightforward to test API routes in Laravel - just do the setup, make the request and check the response is correct and any changes have been made.

Comment: Does it means that if I wrote a Notification test on Unit, I should write it one more time on Feature? I still have a little bit confusion about what stuff to test in where.